# Adding a chart template to a slide using Ribbon

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I am making a company ribbon and want to add charts from there. I have Company chart template, which I want to add using VBA code.

Is there any way to add my Power Point custom template chart to a slide using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to add a custom chart in vba (might be wrong) but you can add any old chart and apply your chart template.

ocht.ApplyChartTemplate [path to chart template]